# Add objects to list with AngularJS and Django. Html page doesn't recognize js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, django

I'm trying to add objects to a list with AngularJS and Django. I had some code working to just count the amount of clicks I do and worked further on that. But now I have more code it seems like my html page doesn't recognize my javascript controller anymore. I tried it again from scratch but without success. What am I doing wrong?

html page:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calc</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="coco">
    <div ng-controller="cocoCtrl">
        <p>CALCULATING BONDS</p>
        <div>
            <input placeholder="Cashflow value" type="number" ng-model="value">
            <input placeholder="Cashflow date" type="date" ng-model="date">
            <!-- new cashflow submitted here -->
            <button ng-click="submitCashflow(value,date)">Cashflow</button>
        </div>

        <div id="cashflow-target">
            <div  ng-repeat="cashflow in cashflows">
                <div class="cashflow-value"> [[ cashflow.value ]]</div>
                <div class="cashflow-date"> [[ cashflow.date ]]</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{%static "js/controller.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{%static "js/app.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{%static "js/cashflow.js" %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

controller.js:

```
app = angular.module('coco',[]);

app.controller('cocoCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){

    $scope.cashflows = {};

    Cashflow.query(function(response) {
        $scope.cashflows = response;
    });

    $scope.submitCashflow= function(value, date) {
        var cashflow = new Cashflow({value: value, date: date});
        cashflow.$save(function(){
            $scope.cashflows.unshift(cashflow);
        })
    };

    $scope.save = function(){
        $(".data").html("Click" + $scope.cashflows);
        $scope.num += 1;
    };


}]);
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?..

Comment: @Sayse : rc_coco-master/coco/coco/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py:89: RemovedInDjango110Warning: The context_instance argument of render_to_string is deprecated.
  using=using)